# Beautiful Soup PYTHON - inside tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Little problem with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "http://www.cnnvd.org.cn/web/vulnerability/querylist.tag"

req = requests.get(link)
web = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web, "lxml")

cve_name = []
cve_link = []

for par_ in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'fl'}):
    for link_ in par_.find_all('p'):
        for text_ in link_.find_all('a'):
            print (text_.string)
            print (text_['href'])
            print ("==========")
            #cve_name.append(text_.string)
            #cve_link.append(text_['href'])
```

And it gives me twice records :V That probably is easy to solve :V

Comment: `a.text` and `a['href']`

Comment: I know how to get link and text, but it give's mi it twice :V

Comment: are you sure you have only one <p> in HTML ? and only one <div> ?

Comment: There is few <div class="fl"> tags and inside them are only one <p> tag. For example there is a 10 div tags and inside them are only one <p> tag. I want to get only 10 unique elements inside <p><a href="sss">text</a></p> tags. Finally after 'findall' i get 20 elements, first ten are unique and its okey but next ten are the same like previous.

Comment: i run your code with your HTML and I get only one element - so if it is only part of HTML then you may have more <div class="fl"><p></div>` in it.

Comment: do you have `<p>` in every `<div class="fl">` ? Then you should get ever `<p>` in result - you use `find_all()` to get all `<div>` and `find_all()` to get all `<p>` in `<div>`. You don't use `find()` to get only first element. You don't use index (ie. `tag_[0]`) or slicing (ie. `tag_[0:1]`) to check only one `<div>`

Comment: you would have to add in question full code and HTML - with this part I can't reproduce problem. I get only one result.

Comment: Okey i added example of code and HTML. ;)

Comment: for new HTML and your code I get every url only once. Maybe you have it in some loop which repeat all.

Comment: Nope, there is only one "for" loop with "for par_ ..." Daaamn ;D its propably little thing

Comment: you have to put full working example which gives you wrong result. test it before you put in question. With parts of code I can't reproduce problem. Or maybe you read many pages and every page has the same links which you see as one result.

Comment: Okey, posted. There is everything ;)

Comment: see my answer - the same elements are in two places so you get the same urls two times.

Answer (score 1):

The same elements are in two places on page so you have to use `find()`/`find_all()` to select only one place i.e `find(class_='list_list')` in

```
soup.find(class_='list_list').find_all('div', attrs={'class':'fl'}):
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "http://www.cnnvd.org.cn/web/vulnerability/querylist.tag"

req = requests.get(link)
web = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web, "lxml")

cve_name = []
cve_link = []


for par_ in soup.find(class_='list_list').find_all('div', attrs={'class':'fl'}):
    print(len(par_))
    for link_ in par_.find_all('p'):
        for text_ in link_.find_all('a'):
            print (text_.string)
            print (text_['href'])
            print ("==========")
            #cve_name.append(text_.string)
            #cve_link.append(text_['href'])
```

Comment: Oooh, there was a problem :V  Thanks. ;)!

Answer (score 0):

How about this. I used css selectors to do the same.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

link = "http://www.cnnvd.org.cn/web/vulnerability/querylist.tag"
res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

for item in soup.select('.fl p a'):
    print("Item: {}\nItem_link: {}".format(item.text,urljoin(link,item['href'])))
```

Partial Output:

```
Item: CNNVD-201712-811
Item_link: http://www.cnnvd.org.cn/web/xxk/ldxqById.tag?CNNVD=CNNVD-201712-811
Item: CNNVD-201712-810
Item_link: http://www.cnnvd.org.cn/web/xxk/ldxqById.tag?CNNVD=CNNVD-201712-810
Item: CNNVD-201712-809
Item_link: http://www.cnnvd.org.cn/web/xxk/ldxqById.tag?CNNVD=CNNVD-201712-809
```